# How to write nested dictionary values into an excel sheet along with column names?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, xlsx

How to write nested dictionary values into an excel sheet along with column names ?
Python dictionary looks as below:

```
`test_dict = { 'posts': {'item_1': 1, 'item_2': 8, 'item_3': 105, 'item_4': 324, 'item_5': 313},'edits': {'item_1': 1, 'item_2': 8, 'item_3': 61, 'item_4': 178, 'item_5': 163},'views': {'item_1': 2345, 'item_2': 330649, 'item_3': 12920402, 'item_4': 46199102, 'item_5': 43094955}}`
```

I want to write the data into excel sheet, where COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5 are not present in dictionary (separately defined).

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
 1   ,8   ,61 ,178 ,163
 1   ,8   ,105,324 ,313
2345,330649,12920402,46199102,43094955
```

Code to write the dictionary values into **CSV**:

```
f = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
f.write('COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5\n')

for key, value in test_dict.iteritems() :
        f.write(str(test_dict[str(key)]["item_1"])+","+str(test_dict[str(key)]["item_2"])+","+str(test_dict[str(key)]["item_3"])+","+str(test_dict[str(key)]["item_4"])+","+str(test_dict[str(key)]["item_5"])+"\n");
f.close()
```

In this case, How to convert **CSV** to **XLSX** (any one-liner ?)

**How to write these dictionary values into excel-sheet directly as in above format ?**

Can you please help me here ?

Comment: Do you have any excel library installed? Or Pandas?

Comment: yeah, xlsxwriter.